# How to setup Birthday Email on Automation Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio

I want to send a birthday email.

So I already connect both the cloud and get the record of contact object into the sync data extension and I also created a standard data extension in marketing cloud.

Now when I am creating Automation Studio and select first activity as a query which will update my standard data extension.

Now my question how to send an email who has a birthday today only?

So can anyone suggest me a query to achieve this?

Note: I created one field in contact named "Birthday" and another field in contact is for "BirthdayCurrentYear" this is the formula field.

Comment: If your birthdate is in one field, then it would be simpler to user a filter definition instead of a query.

Comment: @harley Ok!!  so if i am using filter definition and testing the automation with the same  year and date i don't receive any email. so, my approach is -                                              I created Automation in which i am adding 3 steps.                                               
1. Create a query which get all the data from syn data extension to standard data extension .
2. Create a filter definition in which i add a filter for (Formula field which i created to get current year) so the filter is field Name equals to today().
3. Add email.

Answer (score 2):

While there are a handful of ways to do this, I think you are looking for this one. Hope this helps. When I run the below today, it send me 2 of the 3 people in the DE. Best of luck to you!

---

1. Ensure your DE a) sendable, and b) has the is a “date” type. You can see it’s a date by the calendar icon in the Name column to the left of the word "Birthday."

[image]
[image]

2. In Email > Subscribers, create a filter for a) Data Extension, and b) make the filter “anniversary of” today.

[image]
[image]

3. Go into Automation Studio-activites, create a filter that selects the filter made in #2 as the “Filter Definition.”

[image]

4. Go into Email > Content and then build an email.

[image]

5. Go into Automation Studio-activites, create an email that selects the email made in #4 and use your DE in the “select audience” step.

[image]

6. Create a new automation.
   6a. I’m assuming Starting Source = Schedule
   6b. 1.1 Will be the filter you built in automation studio
   6c. 2.1 Email will be the email you built in automation studio.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much !!! I am going to implement this now.